# How to remove these footnotes from text

Tags: r, replace, nlp, data-cleaning

Alright so I have minimal experience with RStudio, I've been googling this for hours now and I'm fed up-- I don't care about the pride of figuring it out on my own anymore, I just want it done. I want to do some stuff with Canterbury Tales-- [the Middle English version on Gutenberg.](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/22120/22120-h/22120-h.htm)

Downloaded the plaintext, trimmed out the meta data, etc but it's chock-full of "helpful" footnotes and I can't figure out how to cut them out.  EX:

"And shortly, whan the sonne was to reste,

So hadde I spoken with hem everichon,

That I was of hir felawshipe anon,

And made forward erly for to ryse,

To take our wey, ther as I yow devyse.

```
19. Hn. Bifel; E. Bifil.   23. E. were; _rest_ was.   24. E. Hn.
compaignye.   26, 32. E. felaweshipe.   Hl. pilgryms; E. pilgrimes.
34. E. oure

But natheles, whyl I have tyme and space,..."
```

I at least have the vague notion that this is a grep/regex puzzle. Looking at the text in TextEdit, each bundle of footnotes is indented by 4 spaces, and the next verse starts with a capitalized word indented by (edit: 4 spaces as well).

So I tried downloading the package qdap and using the rm_between function to specify removal of text between four spaces and a number; and two spaces and a capital letter ("    [0-9]","  "[A-Z]") to no avail.

I mean, this isn't nearly as simple as "make the text lowercase and remove all the numbers dur-hur" which all the tutorials are so helpfully offering. But I'm assuming this is a rather common thing that people have to do when dealing with big texts. Can anyone help me? Or do I have to go into textedit and just manually delete all the footnotes?

EDIT: I restarted the workspace today and all I have is a scan of the file, each line stored in a character vector, with the Gutenburg metadata trimmed out:

```
text<- scan("thefilepath.txt, what = "character", sep = "\n")  
start <-which(text=="GROUP A. THE PROLOGUE.")  
end <-which(text==""God bringe us to the Ioye . that ever schal be!")  
cant.lines.v <- text[start:end]
```

And that's it so far. Eventually I will

```
cant.v<- paste(cant.lines.v, collapse=" ")
```

And then **strsplit** and **unlist** into a vector of individual words-- but I'm assuming, to get rid of the footnotes, I need to **gsub** and replace with blank space, and that will be easier with each separate line? I just don't know how to encode the pattern I need to cut. I believe it is 4 spaces followed by a number, then continuing on until you get to 4 spaces followed by a capitalized word and a second word w/o numbers and special characters and punctuation.

I hope that I'm providing enough information, I'm not well-versed in this but I am looking to become so...thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now, as is, your post is too broad of a question. You should include the R code that you have used so far and narrow down your difficulties a bit more.

Comment: Duh. thanks a lot.

Comment: But if I *did* want to regex it, how would I?

Comment: Been thinking about this for a while: it appears to me that there are patterns in the footnotes: `19. Hn. Bifel; E. Bifil.   23. E. were; _rest_ was.   24. E. Hn.
compaignye.   26, 32. E. felaweshipe.   Hl. pilgryms; E. pilgrimes.
34. E. oure`. For example, besides the numbers, full stops, spaces, isn't it that `E.`and `Hn.` and, perhaps, `Hl.`re-occur in these footnotes? Is there a 'vocabulary' of abbreviations used in the footnotes. If so, then this could be used for a regex.